# Conditional Sum in Array

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab

I have 2 arrays, A and B. I want to form a new array C with same dimension as B where each element will show SUM(A) for A > B

Below is my working code

```
A = [1:1:1000]
B=[1:1:100]
for n = 1:numel(B)
    C(n) = sum(A(A>B(n)));
end
```

However, when A has millions of rows and B has thousands, and I have to do similar calculations for 20 array-couples,it takes insane amount of time.

Is there any faster way?

For example, histcounts is pretty fast, but it counts, rather than summing.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had the right ideas with `histcounts`, as you are basically "accumulating" certain `A` elements based on `binning`. This binning operation could be done with [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html). Listed in this post is a solution that starts off with similar steps as listed in [`@David's answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31507449/3293881) and then uses `histc` to bin and sum up selective elements from `A` to get us the desired output and all of it in a vectorized manner. Here's the implementation -

```
%// Sort A and B and also get sorted B indices
sA = sort(A);
[sB,sortedB_idx] = sort(B);

[~,bin] = histc(sB,sA);     %// Bin sorted B onto sorted A
C_out = zeros(1,numel(B));  %// Setup output array

%// Take care of the case when all elements in B are greater than A  
if sA(1) > sB(end)
    C_out(:) = sum(A);
end

%// Only do further processing if there is at least one element in B > any element in A
if any(bin)
    csA = cumsum(sA,'reverse'); %// Reverse cumsum on sorted A

    %// Get sum(A(A>B(n))) for every n, but for sorted versions
    valid_mask = cummax(bin) - bin ==0;
    valid_mask2 = bin(valid_mask)+1 <= numel(A);
    valid_mask(1:numel(valid_mask2)) = valid_mask2;
    C_out(valid_mask) = csA(bin(valid_mask)+1);

    %// Rearrange C_out to get back in original unsorted version
    [~,idx] = sort(sortedB_idx);
    C_out = C_out(idx);
end
```

Also, please remember when comparing the result from this method with the one from the original for-loop version that there would be slight variations in output as this vectorized solution uses `cumsum` which computes a running summation and as such would have large cumulatively summed numbers being added to individual elements that are comparatively very small, whereas the for-loop version 
would sum only selective elements. So, `floating-precision issues` would come up there.

Comment: sounds interesting .. I'll give a try and let you know the result ... thanks a lot

Comment: @AbdFahim Awesome! Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Okay .. just ran the solutions of 1 array-pair with A having 1.67 million data and B having 0.1 million points. When I run 3 solution in series within same script, Conventional for loop took 3.478195s, @David's solution took 3.120483s where as Divakar's solution took 0.021036s. So a huge improvement. But, David's solution result exactly matches (99% accuracy) with for loop, where as Divakar's solution has around 1% - 10% error with the for loop. I'll dig down more on Divakar's solution to check where this difference is coming from. Thanks guys.

Comment: @AbdFahim Check out the edited code and the comments at the end of the solution?

Comment: @Divakar .. the modified version also gives same result. anyway I guess I can live with that small deviation as it has incredible improvement in speed. Thanks a lot

Comment: @AbdFahim Can either A or B be 2D matrices, or are they both always vectors?

Comment: both A and B are always row vectors e.g. dim(A) is 1*X, and dim(B) is 1*Y .... B is actually constant and sorted all the time, as B = .1:.1:10000

Comment: @AbdFahim See if the edited code makes any positive difference? Also, what's your criteria for error? Are you using some tolerance value between the results? As a suggestion you can use something like this : `if max(abs(C(:) - C_out(:))) > 1e-5, disp('there is error'), end`. Here, `1e-5` is the tolerance, which you can vary.

Comment: @Divakar .. the error has reduced significantly with less than 0.5% error with the for loop value. A big thumbs up and thanks a lot !

Comment: @AbdFahim Very awsome! A big relief for me! Thanks for updating me!

Comment: entirely my pleasure .. :)

Answer (score 7):

Depending on the size of your arrays (and your memory limitations), the following code might be slightly faster:

```
C = A*bsxfun(@gt,A',B);
```

Though it's vectorized, however, it seems to be bottlenecked (perhaps) by the allocation of memory. I'm looking to see if I can get a further speedup. Depending on your input vector size, I've seen up to a factor of 2 speedup for large vectors.

Comment: Interesting approach. Perhaps the memory limitation problem could be reduced if `B` was processed in blocks.

Comment: @RafaelMonteiro Perhaps. I'll think about this more (this question's been on my mind). Clearly David' solution is faster, thought.

Comment: thanks ... I will benchmark between the processes ... the speed is of prime importance as I have to handle 30-40 arrays with 2 million data in each array

Comment: I got some strange error "Error using * 
Requested 1499100000x1 (11.2GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. " . Ran the solution for 1 array-pair with A having 1.67 million data and B having 0.1 million points

Answer (score 6):

Here's a method that is a bit quicker, but I'm sure there is a better way to solve this problem.

```
a=sort(A); %// If A and B are already sorted then this isn't necessary!
b=sort(B);
c(numel(B))=0; %// Initialise c
s=cumsum(a,2,'reverse'); %// Get the partial sums of a
for n=1:numel(B)
    %// Pull out the sum for elements in a larger than b(n)
    c(n)=s(find(a>b(n),1,'first'));
end
```

According to some very rough tests, this seems to run a bit better than twice as fast as the original method.

Comment: Thanks .. it works .. but still causing memory outage sometimes ... the only issue is I am handling very large amount of data ...